# Classify slander content

Tags: python, ruby, machine-learning, nlp

I am making an automation application that can collect facebook content, analyze the content to detect the slander comments. Is there any ruby tool to do this such kind of detection? I just found some tool to do sentiment analysis but It is not what I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to identify slander with an algorithm. Heck, it is more often than not impossible for a *human* to identify slander.

Here is an example:

> "John Smith has a big pimple on his butt!"

Is this slander?

Well, it depends:

If John Smith has a big pimple on his butt, then it is simply a true statement. It is not slander. For a statement to be slander, it has to be *untrue*.

Okay, so what if John Smith does not have a big pimple on his butt, is it slander then? We don't know.

If I *truly believe* that John Smith has a big pimple on his butt, then it is not slander. It is only slander if the statement is made in *bad faith*. If I simply have bad information, then it is not slander.

Okay, so what if I know that the statement I am making is false? Then it surely must be slander, right? Actually, no. It depends on how, why, and in what context that statement was made. If it were said in a *satirical context*, for example, then it would not be slander but would instead be protected as the expression of free speech and art.

There is no way in which an algorithm can judge the full historical, societal, and artistic context of a statement. It is very hard even for humans to do that.

As an example, read up on the [*Böhmermann affair*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6hmermann_affair).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clear my mind, sorry for a stupid question :)